# Regex for string with two vowels and three consonants

Tags: regex

I've group of five character strings that are combinations of characters which go from *a* to *z* (a-z) and I need to narrow them down to strings with two vowels, i.e.

`*agyge,aohhh,itgtu..etc`

I thought this pattern`^[^(aeiou)]*[aeiou]{2}[^(aeiou)]*$` would work but it doesn't. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [kabb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21896853/2812842), to **capture** the entire string, you need to wrap his answer in a capture group, and make the current capture group a non-capture group:

```
^((?:[^aeiou]*[aeiuo]){2}[^aeiou]*)$
```

Example:

```
agyge # matched
aohhh # matched
itgtu # matched
artdd # no match
bnghk # no match
```

**Demo:** http://regex101.com/r/gU1qU0

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
([^aeiou]*[aeiuo]){2}[^aeiou]*
```

It tries looking for sets of characters that contain 0 or more consonants followed by a vowel, twice. If it manages that, then it matches any remaining consonants.

If it matches the whole string, then it satisfies your conditions.